# Gnome doesn't recognize my audio card

Tags: gnome, sound, alsa

I have an Asus Vivobook e200h with a fresh installation of Gnome and the audio doesn't work. In the audio settings, the audio output is "output dummy".

Here is the output for `aplay -l`:

```
aplay: device_list:268: no audio card found...
```

Running `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` gives no output.

I also tried to reinstall all `alsa` packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS